Ссылка на вложения chat-exporter
Создал тикет бота, который создает транскрипт тикета после закрытия. Бот сохраняет фото, видео и тд на локальную машину правильно, но как мне сделать загрузку на файловый менеджер?
file_handler = AttachmentToLocalFileHostHandler(
    base_path="/app/BotRUSSIA/accets",
    url_base="https://github.com/dpalik500/transcripts/upload/main"
)

Что нужно сделать, чтобы в url_base все верно загружалось и в транскрипте потом можно было это увидеть? Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.
